# GIT - Issue with cherry-pick (File changed not reflecting after merged in GitHub)

Tags: git, github, merge

I had some conflict in merging my **development** branch code to **master** and decided to create a Integration branch. I did **cherry-pick** all the required commits from development branch to Integration branch.

Now , when I committed the changes to Integration branch it considered all the merged(using cherry-pick) as new commit. I am fine with this. But after the merge , when i compare **development** and **Integration** branch the difference in **File changed** are same.

Did any one had similar issue. Thanks

Here are the  steps i did on the scenario, I created a file in local development branch and then switched to integration branch and used cherry-picked to merge the commit in development branch. The local branches git diff integration...development did not show any difference after cherry-pick, which is good... but on github when i compare both development and integration branch the File Changes are still showing. When there are lot of commits I cherry-picked I am finding difficult to see which are the commits are picked.

```
git status
# On branch master
nothing to commit, working directory clean

git checkout -b development
Switched to a new branch 'development'

git diff master..development
vim test_cherry_pick.txt

git status
# On branch development
# Untracked files:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
#
#   test_cherry_pick.txt
nothing added to commit but untracked files present (use "git add" to track)

git add test_cherry_pick.txt
git commit
[development 0b88adc] Added temp file to test cherry_pick
1 file changed, 1 insertion(+)
create mode 100644 test_cherry_pick.txt

git diff master..development
diff --git a/test_cherry_pick.txt b/test_cherry_pick.txt
new file mode 100644
index 0000000..d7b8e14
--- /dev/null
+++ b/test_cherry_pick.txt
@@ -0,0 +1 @@
+This file is to test cherry_pick

git checkout master
Switched to branch 'master'

git checkout -b integration
Switched to a new branch 'integration'

git diff master..integration

git cherry-pick 0b88ad
[integration 297e93b] Added temp file to test cherry_pick
1 file changed, 1 insertion(+)
create mode 100644 test_cherry_pick.txt

git diff development..integration
```

Note: I used GitHub GUI tool to publish the integration and development branches to origin.
[image: screen shot of comparing development and integration branch in GitHub]

Comment: Could you describe the situation on a commit diagram similar to those used in `git merge --help` or `git rebase --help`? You may use `git log --graph` for this.

Comment: Please show a pair of commits where you think the diffs shouldn't be the same for the original and the cherry-picked one.  Cherry-picking is supposed to apply identical changes, so it's hard to see what you're asking here.

Comment: can you please see my updated question. I tried to create a scenario for this issue.The local branch shows no difference(good) , but when comparing in github origin the difference are still shown.

Answer (score 0):

When cherry-picking git does not understand that the commits are actually the same. It appears that Github Compare will do a git request-pull which shows the cherry-picked commit as as different from "same" commit with the new ID.